# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Movies' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF enityframework

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, database-migration

How do i solve the above problem? I am doing a project with ASP.NET and i am using code-first approach, i created a migration and now when i want to update databse with update-database it pops up that message

Comment: It looks like you're trying to supply a value to an `IDENTITY` column.  See if you can modify your code to either set the value for this field as `NULL` or to not set the value at all.

Comment: You need to set IDENTITY_INSERT ON for that table and then reset it to OFF

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting IDENTITY to ON in the AddNewMovie migration